# Formatting UNIX date to readable format

Tags: php, date

I'm just testing a script that displays events and I'm trying to compare whether the date is before or after today. For viewing purposes I just wanted to output all dates in readable format.

Currently I'm printing out the array that just spits out all the dates in UNIX format. How would I print all of the dates already formatted to the ('l d F Y') format?

```
    $events = array();
    $date = 16;

    for ( $i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++ ) {
        $events[] = mktime(0, 0, 0, 3, $date, 2011);        
        $date++;
    }

    print_r($events);

    echo date('l d F Y', $events[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood well your question:

```
foreach($events as $event_date)
{
  echo date('l d F Y', $event_date)."<br />\n";
}
```

Comment: As you wrote that I just figured the same exact solution out. Thanks!